# Can I accept text in Prompt.Choice that is not in list of options?

Tags: c#, botframework

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{   
    PromptDialog.Choice(context,
            this.ResumeAfter,
            options: new string[] { "Yes", "No" },
            prompt: "Are you ready to continue?",
            retry: "Not a valid option",
            attempts: 3);
}

public async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> argument)
{
    var message = await argument;

    //this sets bool-proceed to false if message is QUIT, for example
    await ProcessTextMessage(context, message); 

    if (proceed)
    {
        bool result;
        if (bool.TryParse(message, out result) && result)
        {
            //do stuff for YES
        }
        else
        {
            //this is NO
            await context.PostAsync("What else can I help you with?");
            context.Done("DONE");
        }
    }
}
```

This will display Yes and No, and it will only accept either Yes or No.
Is there a way to accept special tokens (like HELP, RESET, BACK) which I can then handle on my own?

Something like how the Forms Dialog can always handle HELP, BACK, QUIT, etc.

Here is my ProcessTextMessage method:

```
private async Task ProcessTextMessage(IDialogContext context, string message)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case "QUIT":
            proceed = false;

            await context.PostAsync($"**QUIT** Application was triggered. What else can I help you with today?");
            context.Done("QUIT");
            break;

        case "RESET":
            proceed = false;

            await context.PostAsync($"**RESET** Application was triggered.");
            await StartAsync(context);
            break;

        case "HELP":
            await context.PostAsync($"Some other actions you can use: **QUIT**, **RESET**, **BACK**.");
            break;

        case "BACK":
            switch (CurrentState)
            {
                //in progress
                //calls previous method
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is NO - based on my discussion with JasonSowers. What did work is creating a reusable Dialog (ThumbnailCards for buttons) and intercepting the user input MessageReceived(). If the input is a reserved token then do: context.Done(userInput) and handle it outside the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a great opportunity to use [Scorables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-scorable-dialogs).  That way no matter where your user is in the dialog you can intercept and act on commands like "quit" or "help".  There is a great [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnU3lPHhv88).

Another way you can do this if to use a switch statement or if statements on `Activity.Text` when using `ImBack` or `MessageBack` to do different things depending what your user types code example below:

```
    var message = await result as Activity;
    switch (message.Text.ToLower())
    {
        case "yes":
            //do yes stuff
            break;
        case "no":
            //do no stuff
            break;
        case "quit":
            //do quit stuff
            break;
        case "help":
            //do help stuff
            break;
    }
```

the below code is "working"  but I'm not exactly sure what your goal is.  I would first move the prompt out of `MessageReceivedAsync`.  anyways here is the code:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    private bool proceed;
    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        PromptDialog.Choice(context,
            this.ResumeAfter,
            options: new string[] { "Yes", "No" },
            prompt: "Are you ready to continue?",
            retry: "Not a valid option",
            attempts: 3);

    }

    public async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;

        //this sets bool-proceed to false if message is QUIT, for example
        await ProcessTextMessage(context, message);

        bool proceed =true;
        if (proceed)
        {
            bool result;
            if (bool.TryParse(message, out result) && result)
            {
                //do stuff for YES
            }
            else
            {
                //this is NO
                await context.PostAsync("What else can I help you with?");
                context.Done("DONE");
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessTextMessage(IDialogContext context, string message)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case "QUIT":
                proceed = false;

                await context.PostAsync($"**QUIT** Application was triggered. What else can I help you with today?");
                context.Done("QUIT");
                break;

            case "RESET":
                proceed = false;

                await context.PostAsync($"**RESET** Application was triggered.");
                await StartAsync(context);
                break;

            case "HELP":
                await context.PostAsync($"Some other actions you can use: **QUIT**, **RESET**, **BACK**.");
                break;

            case "BACK":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to do the second approach? ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Activity> argument) causes an error on Prompt.Choice because this.ResumeAfter is expecting IAwaitable<string> argument ?

Comment: For the 2nd approach, it can be done by adding Help / Reset / Back as choices and handle them correctly. By the way for Yes/No questions, (s)he should use PromptDialog.Confirm instead.

Comment: @NicolasR I don't want to show Help/Reset/Back as actual buttons. And I did originally have PromptDialog.Confirm but I was trying to see if accepting strings would help in my issue...

Comment: Can you please post the code you are trying to get to work with the resume after method included

Comment: @JasonSowers I edited the post to show more code. I am also trying to use ThumbnailCard for Yes or No - maybe that is what you meant when you presented Option2? That's the only way I can think of to have IAwaitable<Activity> - but I am not yet successful with this attempt

Comment: you should not have your code in the `StartAsync` method to begin with, let me plug this in and try it out

Comment: Thank you! I will wait on that - your feedback is very helpful. I was also successful using ThumbnailCard but would definitely want to see your input about my current code.

Comment: Can you also add your `ProcessTextMessage` method into your code?

Comment: Done. I put it at the bottom because I got the "your post is mostly code" error when saving my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163361/discussion-between-jasonsowers-and-oyen).

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this out of the dialog, as you want to change the flow of the dialog. Hence, you can control this out of the dialog by conditioning on the text of user.